# Where is the asp.net configuration button in solution explorer in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In visual studio 2010 you can find asp.net configuration button in solution explorer: hammer an' a globe.
There is no such a button in Visual Studio 2012.
 How can i access asp.net configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Simply click on your project, or any file within your project (**Don't select the entire Solution**);
2. Click the "PROJECT" menu, last Menu item is "ASP.NET Configuration".